# How should I make my jquery validator work?(I think it doesn't wait for remote rule)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, jquery-validate

I am implementing a form validator with jQuery. However, it never works. Instead of showing any message, it shows an error. How can I make the validator work?

As I searched for other questions asking for similar problems, I've found some suggestions. One was changing *remote* into *synchronousRemote*, and one was adding *submitHandler* into the validator. I've tried them all, but nothing changed.

This is my validator code:

```
$("#createMember-form").validate({
            ignore: "",
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    pattern: /^[a-zA-Z ]$/,
                    maxlength: 45
                },
                id: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    maxlength: 15,
                    pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/,
                    remote: {
                        url: "/member/checkUnique",
                        data: document.getElementById("#idField").value,
                        dataFilter: function (data) {
                            return data;
                        }
                    }
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    maxlength: 15,
                    pattern: /^(?=.*[a-z])[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]+$/
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "This field is required.",
                    pattern: "Your name should be written in English.",
                    maxlength: "It can't be longer than 45 letters."
                },
                id: {
                    required: "This field is required.",
                    pattern: "Your ID should be written in Romaji and numbers.",
                    minlength: "It can't be shorter than 6 letters.",
                    maxlength: "It can't be longer than 15 letters.",
                    remote: "The user using " + $("#idField").val() + " already exists."
                },
                password: {
                    required: "This field is required.",
                    pattern: "Your ID should be written in Romaji and numbers.",
                    minlength: "It can't be shorter than 6 letters.",
                    maxlength: "It can't be longer than 15 letters."
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                form.submit()
            }
        });
```

Building database table, I'd set up the entry *id* to be unique, the entry *name*, *id*, and *password* to never be null. And before going inside the validator, the for is submitted, and the error with the database occurs.
I guess that the reason is that it doesn't wait for the *remote* rule to be checked. If it is right, what should I for the form to wait? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: `synchronousRemote` isn't a standard validator method. Have you added it in to the page? Also note that it's redundant as there's a `remote()` validator built in which you should be using as it's async.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan OK, thank you. I think the suggestion of changing into *synchronousRemote* was wrong. However, I don't think it is the solution because I've tried.